# How to generate git sha1 of current repository

Tags: git, hash, commit, sha1

I am trying to generate the current git sha1 of a repository. 
I don't want the last commit sha1 that can be generated using a set of git command. I want the sha1 that will be used in the next commit (obviously if files are not changed).

I would like to be able to generate an header file containing a define of the sha1 repository. This will allows me to match executable with relative git commit and viceversa.

The problem is that not every executable is created with a stable commit (especially during development phase).

For this reason I choose to include both:
- Last commit sha1
- Current repository sha1

If they match it means that the current  executable is created using a stable commit. Otherwise it means that you can just know what is the starting commit of your executable.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Construct the commit object content and calculate its checksum.

Comment: However, if no files changed, why do you even need to make another commit? The SHA of the tip commit should be good enough? Which problem are you trying to solve here?

Comment: However, what you will calculate is *one possible commit sha*, not **the** next commit sha. The time at which the commit is made is relevant for the checksum, which means that you will have to predict the future to be able to do this. Let me know when you've solved that problem and we can get cracking on the question you asked. Please explain more what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Maybe you could use [git describe](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-describe) with `--dirty` (and `--always`) flag?

Answer (score 3):

https://gist.github.com/masak/2415865

I just found out (using the link above) that commit sha1 in git depends on commit author and not just by the repository files. So I think that achieving what I want is not possible.

Comment: Correct, it is also dependent on the time at which the commit is made, which even if you can ensure you know who is going to commit the next commit, you cannot predict when. Additionally, the comment is also part of the SHA. In short, you will need to predict the future.

Comment: Thanks Lasse. Please read my question update. Do you think is there an alternative way to achieve what I need?

Comment: Yes, set up a build server, that way you will always know exactly which commit you built from.

Comment: what is a build server?